# Probability of voting in a group

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

I encountered a math problem in a competition. I know probability but I'm not good at combinatorics. Under the problem, I show my thoughts. If I make any false assumption, I'd appreciate it if you correct me.

> We have $n$ parties and $n$ people have to choose between them and they vote randomly. What's the probability that (only) one party will not get a vote?

This is a variation with repetition and therefore I can calculate the number of variations with the formula $n^m$. In this case it would be $n^n$. This is also the total possible outcomes of the probability.

I don't know how to calculate the number of variations where only one party gets no vote. If I knew the number, I could calculate the probability with $\frac{?}{n^n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Give $(n-1)$ parties 1 vote each and you will have $(n-1)$ options for last vote